# Multithreaded(Hyperthreading) v/s multicore processors

Tags: multicore, cpu-architecture, hyperthreading

I am doing a parallel computing course at my university and apparently we need to know the architectures at programmer's level. Can anyone tell what is the motivation for developing multicore processors? Why multithreaded processors won't suffice? Why do we need to distribute the pipelines over multiple cores rather than having them on a single large core?

Answer (score 6):

As CPUs become smaller and faster they approach several physical limits which makes it more costly to continue on the current path:

- CPUs of today (intel) are fabricated in 22 nm (AMD in 32 nm) technology which roughly translates to 90 silicon atom diameters. A theoretical limit should be one atom diameter but in practice you'll need much more than that. How many?
- The speed of electricity. Assuming a speed of 2/3 of the speed of light we find that on a 2 GHz CPU electricity will travel 10 cm (about 4 inches) during a clock cycle. If it is to do something worthwhile - such as perform an addition or similar - it needs to pass through a system of inter-connected devices which performs the addition and these devices must be able to switch states at a fraction of one cycle (0.5 nanoseconds). How fast can they be made to switch?
- The higher the frequency driving a CPU the more power it consumes. The more power consumed the more heat produced. The more heat produced the more cooling required or the CPU will melt during operation. AMD's newest FX processors consume 220W of power - more than two 100 Watt light bulbs - and run at 4.7 and sometimes turbo to 5 GHz. "Should" the cooling system be more expensive than the CPU itself? In enthusiast systems it sometimes is but not in mainstream systems - they would be too expensive to buy.

This is the reason why CPU manufacturers have gone to multi-core. In theory four cores will have four times the processing capacity of one. Some applications can achieve this but most won't. Over time - maybe - more and more applications can make better use of the multiple cores.

At any one time most of the components making up the CPU are not being used and theoretically available for processing. This is the raison d'être for hyper-threading. Two different threads of execution may run in parallel as long as they don't require access to the same component at the same time. But they do, frequently. Then one has to stop and wait for the other.

On a different tack: necessary functionality which can be implemented on-chip will always allow faster execution than if it is elsewhere. External memory will always execute at a small fraction of the internal speed of the CPU. The 80286 integrated memory protection and virtual memory on the CPU chip. This made it much faster than competing designs which implemented the functions off-chip. The 80486 had on-chip L1 caches though variants of 80386 chipsets implemented off-chip caches. Then came the on-chip level 2 (L2) and later L3 caches. Pentium had an external memory interface that was twice as wide to be able to read twice as much data in the same time span. Later there came two or more external memory interfaces. Later the controllers for the external memory were moved on-chip so as to interfere less with normal operation. Memory chips can deliver two (DDR), four (DDR2) or eight (DDR3) times as much data for every access. DDR4 is in the works. As can be seen the interface between the actual CPU and the external memory becomes more and more complicated to be able to eke out that little bit of extra performance. The solutions implemented are based on common access scenarios which best fit the generic cases such that standard software will run a little bit faster. Specialty software tries to make more efficient use of the interface and can achieve astounding performance. Most other software will never ever come close. Quite a few messed-up applications will even fall outside the normal access patterns and become slower because they work against the interface.

If you take a step back you realize that the "best" solution would be if it were possible to have a direct, minimally complicated path between the CPU and external memory. There was once a standard computer which did just that - Compaq Deskpro 386/20 based on the 80386 - and it used static RAM (SRAM) instead of the dynamic RAM (DRAM) which everyone uses today (because it is much, much cheaper per unit of memory). The SRAM was able to keep pace with the CPU which would actually be slower during multiple-cycle instructions.

What I mean to say by this is that many factors affect total hardware performance so saying "CPU performance" can mean any number of things. They all work together and often cooperate to achieve better performance. Sometimes they do the opposite.

Hyper-threads collide when the same resources are being accessed at the same time. Such resources are not limited to functional components in the CPU. The hyper-threads share the same caches and memory interface and will collide there too. Non-hyper-threading multiple cores will collide too but that will be when they access common resources which usually means the L3 cache and mempry interface. As long as they stay within the resources exclusive to them (core, L1 and L2) they run without interruption.

The main memory can deliver data at a maximum rate. In a standard, poorly optimized application it is usually working at 100% of that rate. The optimum would be if the 100% could be evenly divided between the n cores available.

Hardware solutions that are well-designed will allow faster processing than others. Software designed to run more efficiently by taking the hardware design into account will out-perform run-of-the-mill software.

A somewhat complicated answer but this is a complicated subject :-)

Comment: I seriously doubt that any common PCs used SRAM (static RAM) for main memory; you are probably thinking of SDRAM (synchronous dynamic RAM).

Comment: I think you have missed something. SDRAM hasn't been around all that long. It was the DRAM generation preceding DDR I believe. That would be second half of the nineties. The DeskPro 386 was second half of the eighties. Here is a link to memory4less.com and their instructions on upgrading the DeskPro 386 http://www.memory4less.com/confitems.aspx?modelid=80008453. It states "36 sockets for SRAM on main memory board." In those days extra memory was installed chip by chip. The DeskPro 386/16 was very uncommon in its day.

Comment: Okay, SDRAM became common significantly later. What the Deskpro 386 used was Static Column RAM (indicated by [this support document](ftp://g4w2289.houston.hp.com/pub/supportinformation/techpubs/qrg/dp386_rev2_us.pdf)). This is effectively a variant of Fast Page DRAM **not** Static RAM. [This page](http://books.google.com/books?id=-pz8rvnhFDkC&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267) indicates the confusion is not uncommon (the confusion seems very understandable). (Finding this kind of information is not easy; I only found the one document.)

Comment: @Paul A. Clayton: are you really sure the document concerns the original DeskPro 386/16 (1986)? intel introduced a chipset with cache capabilities shortly thereafter that obviated the need for all-SRAM main memory. Also, the original 386/16 only allowed the 80287 at a much lower speed than 8MHz.

Comment: No, not certain, but finding documentation is difficult. It does seem unlikely that a mainline PC would pay the price for SRAM, but that is a weak argument. There is more evidence that the *extended* memory was DRAM. It is *possible* the system supported 2MiB of SRAM and upto 12 MiB of additional (DRAM) memory, but that *seems* unlikely.

Comment: @Paul A. Clayton: the first cache memory controller produced by intel was the 82385/20 (as in 20MHz) and it was copyrighted in 1987. The DeskPro 386/20 introduced in october 1987 sported such a chip. The DeskPro 386/16 was introduced in september 1986. Any RAM chip would have required a 66ns rating or lower. There were no such DRAM chips. But there were SRAM chips. The 82385 typically used 25-45ns pieces. 50-66ns pieces would have been available and less expensive. So to bridge the gap until the 82385 became available that is what Compaq did.

Comment: @Paul A. Clayton: the KTC4000/16 expansion board was a Kingston Technologies product. It was only used in the DeskPro 386/16. Check out pctimeline.info, thecomputerarchive.com, nytimes.com archive for dates of introduction.

Comment: It looks like you are probably right, but that it was a short-lived design decision. [David Hess posted on Real World Technologies](http://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=139592&curpostid=139628) confirming the use of SRAM. (Sadly this comment thread adds nothing to the answer but **is** interesting.)

Comment: I think this was referring to the Dell/PC's Limited systems not Compaq.

Comment: And this makes it clear the Compaq DeskPro 386 used Static Column RAM: http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/microCornucopia/Micro_Cornucopia_%2334_Feb87.pdf

Comment: @Yuhong Bao: I WAS referring to the Compaq Deskpro 386/20. As Paul A. Clayton said it was not static RAM but static column RAM. Please do not edit my post as it will make all comments appear out of place in the discussion. Since I know nothing about the Dell model you refer to I could not have written the post in the first place. Write a post of your own about the Dell machine instead

Comment: But note that "Static Column" is a form of DRAM, so the post before it was edited was also misleading. There is also "nibble" mode DRAM too BTW. Most DRAM in general was "page mode" before it was replaced by EDO.

Answer (score 3):

Multithreaded processors are not actually capable of executing code simultaneously. The only thing they do is virtualize the processor so that to the operating system it looks like two physical cores, this has a slight speed advantage.

A single core processor without hyperthreading may sometimes waste time waiting for an instruction to finish because it needs to fetch data, or it has a cache miss or perhaps a false branch prediction. While out-of-order exection remedies some of this, adding another thread that can take over and use the CPU resources for a while while the other is blocked boosts performance.

However, this single core with hyperthreading still only has one FPU, one ALU, one Control Unit, one memory interface, etc. Because of this limitation, true simultaneous thread execution requires these components to be duplicated. Duplicating the core and specifying an interface between them is alot simpler than a design that would involve trying to balance multiple ALUs or FPUs, with multiple threads in a single core.

Comment: Actually, this is quite inaccurate. If you look up [Hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), you'll see that they DO, in fact, duplicate the registers and program counters for each thread. Multithreaded processors actually do maintain two separate threads of execution, they only share the computing hardware (ALU, FPU, etc). They most certainly don't use round robin context switching; they use the hardware that the other isn't using at the moment. For example, one thread may go ahead while another is waiting for a memory fetch.

Comment: @mebob I see what you mean my understanding was incorrect. I tried to remedy this. Feel free to edit with clarifications, I made it a community wiki. Alternatively, offer your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the width of a single core has geometric costs in silicon area and power consumption.

Making multiple copies of a reasonable-size core has linear costs (+ small overhead for interconnect / coherency).

Making a super-wide CPU just so you can chop it up with SMT (aka Hyperthreading) is insane.  You'd do it that way if you needed monster single-thread performance, and could somehow cool the chip enough to run at clock speeds anywhere near what a narrower design could manage.  (Which you can't.)

There isn't enough instruction-level parallelism in most code to give a big enough improvement to justify a wider design.  Anything you gain in IPC (insns per clock), you'd lose on clock speed because you couldn't run it as fast without overheating.

For example, in 20 years, Intel has gone from 3-wide issue width (original P6 in PPro to Pentium-M), to 4-wide issue width (Core2 to Skylake).  x86 is hard to decode, but SnB-family designs with a uop-cache could easily have a wider OOO pipeline than their decoder throughput.

What has grown more is the amount of execution ports, and the amount of execution units on each port.  In recent Intel designs, the same instruction can run in parallel on different data.  e.g. Haswell and later can execute two FP multiplies per clock.  IvB and earlier only have a throughput of one FP mul per clock, because there is only one FP mul execution unit (on port1).

Older designs (like PIII) only had two ALU execution ports, so one of the three instructions per clock they could manage had to be a memory operation (load or store).  Haswell has four ALU ports (three of which can handle vector instructions).  So whatever the mix of instructions, recent CPUs have a good chance of doing a lot in parallel.

The "inefficiency" of having a lot of die area not doing anything a lot of the time isn't a problem.  It's power that's the real limiter, not die area.  This is why modern CPUs can have so much execution capacity that can't be used at once.

---

Note that hyperthreading can actually slow your code down if it can saturate the execution resources that HT shares between cores.  Or worse, if the extra cache pressure from competitive sharing of the L1/L2 caches leads to a lot more cache misses in each thread.

HT is a big win when one or both threads achieve low instructions per clock (IPC) when given a full core to themselves.  Two out-of-order windows for hiding memory latency is good, and it's extremely good for branch mispredicts.

It's a small win for two threads that bottleneck on different execution units.  (e.g. shuffle unit on port5 vs. add/mul on port0/1).